# How to get structural details of database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need structural details of all user defined database in below format:-

name type details

In which details include- if it is a table than Column A(type,Size),ColumnB(Type,Size)....,ConstraintA,ConstarintB...,IndexeA(Indexed Columns),IndexB(IndexedColumns).....

If it is a function or procedure that Body of that function or procedure.

Below is the query which I have created but it is taking around 8 mins for 10 databases:-

```
CREATE TABLE #modelStructure (Name VARCHAR(500),TYPE VARCHAR(256),DETAILS NVARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @dbTableName NVARCHAR(500)='#modelStructure'
USE MODEL
SELECT * INTO #AllTablesAndViews FROM sys.objects ob WHERE ob.is_ms_shipped=0 AND ob.type IN ('U','V')
SELECT tab.name AS TableName,tab.object_id,tab.type_desc AS Type,col.name AS ColumnName,typ.name AS ColumnType,typ.max_length AS ColumnSize
                ,ob.name AS ConstraintName,trig.name AS TriggerName INTO #tempTableDetails
FROM #AllTablesAndViews tab 
LEFT JOIN sys.columns col ON tab.object_id=col.object_id
LEFT JOIN sys.objects ob ON ob.parent_object_id=tab.object_id
LEFT JOIN sys.triggers trig ON trig.parent_id=tab.object_id
LEFT JOIN sys.types typ ON col.user_type_id=typ.user_type_id
WHERE tab.name <>'sysdiagrams' AND ob.type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT' AND tab.is_ms_shipped=0 
GROUP BY tab.name ,tab.object_id,tab.type_desc ,col.name,typ.name,typ.max_length,ob.name ,trig.name
SELECT * INTO #stuffedTable FROM
(
SELECT ttd.TableName AS Name,ttd.Type, 
'COLUMNS :-'+
STUFF((SELECT ',' + t1.ColumnName+'('+'Type:'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(200),t1.ColumnType)+' Size:'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(200),t1.ColumnSize)+')'
        FROM #tempTableDetails t1 
        WHERE t1.object_id=ttd.object_id 
        GROUP BY t1.TableName,t1.ColumnName,t1.ColumnType,t1.ColumnSize
        ORDER BY t1.ColumnName
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')+' || '+
'CONSTRAINTS:-'+ STUFF((SELECT ',' + t1.ConstraintName 
        FROM #tempTableDetails t1 
        WHERE t1.object_id=ttd.object_id 
        GROUP BY t1.TableName,t1.ConstraintName
        ORDER BY t1.ConstraintName
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')+' || '+   
'TRIGGERS:-'+ STUFF((SELECT ',' + ISNULL(t1.TriggerName,'') 
        FROM #tempTableDetails t1 
        WHERE t1.object_id=ttd.object_id 
        GROUP BY t1.TableName,t1.TriggerName
        ORDER BY t1.TriggerName
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')+' || ' AS Details 

FROM #tempTableDetails ttd 
)t
GROUP BY t.Details,t.Name,t.Type ORDER BY Name

;WITH cteIndexDetails
AS
(

SELECT 
      ind.name IndexName ,
       t.name TableName,
       col.name IndexColumn
FROM 
     sys.indexes ind 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.index_columns ic ON  ind.object_id = ic.object_id and ind.index_id = ic.index_id 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.columns col ON ic.object_id = col.object_id and ic.column_id = col.column_id 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.tables t ON ind.object_id = t.object_id 
WHERE 

      t.is_ms_shipped = 0 
     AND t.name <> 'sysdiagrams'
     AND ic.is_included_column=0 GROUP BY ind.name,t.name,col.name
)
SELECT  id.TableName,'INDEXES :-'+STUFF((SELECT ',' + t1.IndexName +'( Index Column: '+t1.IndexColumn+' )'
        FROM cteIndexDetails t1 
        WHERE t1.TableName=id.TableName 
        GROUP BY t1.TableName,t1.IndexName,t1.IndexColumn
        ORDER BY t1.IndexName
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')AS [IndexDetails] INTO #indexDetails
        FROM cteIndexDetails id GROUP BY TableName

INSERT INTO #modelStructure 
SELECT Name,TYPE,DETAILS 
FROM
(
SELECT st.Name,st.Type,(st.Details+''+id.IndexDetails) AS Details FROM #stuffedTable st INNER JOIN #indexDetails id ON st.Name=id.TableName 


UNION 

SELECT
       r.ROUTINE_NAME       AS 'Name'
      ,r.ROUTINE_TYPE COLLATE database_default AS 'Type'
      ,sm.definition AS 'DETAILS'
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES r 
INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules sm ON sm.object_id=object_id(r.ROUTINE_NAME)
WHERE (ROUTINE_TYPE = 'function' OR ROUTINE_TYPE = 'procedure')
)t ORDER BY t.TYPE,t.Name

DROP TABLE #AllTablesAndViews
DROP TABLE #tempTableDetails
DROP TABLE #stuffedTable
DROP TABLE #indexDetails


DROP TABLE #modelStructure
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to get the structure of a tabel then use 
something like

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'tablename'
```